# Identation coverts to weird arrow while copying code from sublime to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sublimetext3

Copying this piece of code from sublime :

```
# Texts Texts Texts Texts Texts Texts 
for i in range(10):
    #Idented Texxt
    print i
```

results in below, with the line tab in jupyter-notebook. Now if i want to add to the code and do further testing in jupyter, i need to copy this weird arrow instead of hitting tab (else, it shows indentation error). Is there some simple way to change? I can imagine I am missing something really simple and this might not be a problem at all. I tried looking but found no mention of this. I can change all the indentation to space in sublime and this might work while copying but I rather work with tabs, to make codes readable.

[image]

Second image with double tabs, how it looks like in notebook.

[image]

Comment: You could paste to notepad and copy to jupyter, maybe the arrows will disappear

Comment: This is not a problem at all.

Comment: Is that actually there or is that just to display the ident level?

Comment: @Joe this does not work. same problem persists. @  Upsana, it is not a major problem but this does make it annoying to edit a piece of code and test it.

Comment: @littlecat it is there, the arrow is visible in the notebook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the reason that this is happening to you is due to a mismatch in the world view of tools (i.e. Sublime and Jupyter in this case) with regards to tabs versus spaces, a perennial dispute indeed.

In particular in Sublime you have `translate_tabs_to_spaces` turned off because you want to work with physical tab characters. So pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> in Sublime will insert physical tab characters which are visualized via the `tab_size` setting.

On the other hand, according to this issue, [Jupyter does not support indentation via tabs](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10423) when you press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. As such in Jupyter despite your best intentions, when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it's inserting spaces instead. It does however support physical tabs if they're pasted in, which is why it appears the way it does above and why you have to manually paste physical tabs to get the input that you need.

Of these two tools, Sublime allows you to choose whether you use physical tabs or space characters, but Jupyter does not and always wants spaces. The most expedient solution in that case would be to not use tabs in Sublime either and then everything would match up.

Presumably that's not an option for you, so the next best solution would be to bridge the gap by having Sublime provide the data to Jupyter in a way that it expects, which is possible with a simple plugin.

In Sublime, select `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` and replace the stub with this code, then save in the default location that Sublime will prompt you with (your `User` package) with a recognizable name such as `copy_with_spaces.py`:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class CopyWithSpacesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    Copy the selected text to the clipboard, replacing all tab characters with
    spaces based on the tab size in the current view.
    """
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("copy")

        tab_size = self.view.settings().get("tab_size", 4)      
        text = sublime.get_clipboard().expandtabs(tab_size)
        sublime.set_clipboard(text)
```

This implements a new command `copy_with_spaces` which will perform a copy but modify the data on the way through so that any physical tab characters are replaced with the appropriate number of white space characters.

With that in place, you can add a custom key binding to use when you're copying code from Sublime to Jupyter to streamline things. An example might be:

```json
{
    "keys": ["shift+ctrl+c"],
    "command": "copy_with_spaces",
}
```

Comment: Oh my god ! :D Thanks a lot for the solution. It indeed seems like the outcome of eternal space vs tabs. Jupyter should be bit more flexible regarding the identation. I have been dealing with this problem for so long. And it only gets more tedious and annoying more I write scripts with sublime and test it in jupyter.  This solves the problem of pasting from sublime to jupyter. And I, actually, do not have problem in the reverse. If I paste codes from jupyter to sublime it works quite fine. Even if I paste some lines in a block of code. This is again quite weird. And again Thank you very much !

Answer (score 30):

After copying the scripts to Jupyter cells from sublime:

1. Select all the lines with arrows
2. Press **Tab** - This will remove the arrows and add a tab at the beginning of each line
3. Press **Shift + Tab** - This will delete all the added tabs in the step above

Comment: Clean and simple! Wondering why this is not the selected answer.

Comment: Because it doesn't quite explain the reason that the weird characters are occurring. You can imagine an issue where tabs are used somewhere that isn't at the beginning of the code, where this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Guaranteed** Ever easy solution

1. Select all the lines where arrow is showing.
2. Press `Tab`
3. Press `Shift+Tab`